# Document formatting in mongodb while using mongoimport

Tags: mongodb

wanted to get the documents as the below format while importing millions of records from a csv file to mongodb using mongoimport, which command need to use to get this format. Please help.Thanks.

```
    "_id" : {
            "X_id" : 1,
            "y_id" : 2,
            "z_id" : 3
    },
    "name" : "test",
    "allow" : 1,
    "date1" : ISODate("2012-12-31T17:31:02.981Z"),
    "date2" : ISODate("2012-12-31T17:31:02.981Z")
```

}

Comment: Then why did u add the Tag " sql " ?

Comment: Can you show the  csv file sample

Comment: Here the sample CSV file >> 

"X_ID","Y_ID","Z_ID","DATE1","DATE2","ALLOW","NAME"

600985,1,2,22-MAR-13,12-JUL-05,1,"TEST1"

600985,2,3,22-MAR-13,12-JUL-05,1,"TEST2"

600985,3,4,22-MAR-13,12-JUL-05,1,"TEST3"

Answer (score 0):

The `mongoimport` tool is only intended for straightforward import from CSV/TSV/JSON text files. For more complex/custom transformations you will need to create your own import script in your favourite programming language using one of the [supported language drivers](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/) for MongoDB.

If you have millions of records to import, a few approaches that can help speed up the import are:

- use MongoDB [bulk inserts](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-inserts/) to upload batches of rows read from the CSV (i.e. instead of inserting after each line read)
- use a stream-oriented CSV parsing library (some naive CSV parsers can attempt to read the whole file into memory)
- use multiple threads to parse and process the incoming CSV; a simple approach might be to split the CSV into multiple smaller files and execute the imports in parallel